# IIS RewriteMap Rule causes 500 error

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, rewritemap

I am totally new to IIS servers and need to implement some rewrites. 
    The following rule in my    RewriteMaps file causes a 500 error:

```
<add key="/contenttemplates/news.aspx?id=8589976277&LangType=3081&CurrencyType=156" value="/" />
```

While this one works fine:

```
<add key="/offset-air.php" value="/" />
```

I can only assume the query string has something to do with the issue, but I struggle to find a reason as to why this URL would be an issue. Initial google attempts have come up empty.

I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Many Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rewrite maps are causing you issues, you should consider encoding your urls correctly.

An `&` in the URL (in either the key or the value) should be replaced with an `&amp;`.

```
 <add key="/contenttemplates/news.aspx?id=8589976277&LangType=3081&CurrencyType=156" value="/" />
```

would then become:

```
 <add key="/contenttemplates/news.aspx?id=8589976277&amp;LangType=3081&amp;CurrencyType=156" value="/" />
```